# What happens to inactive users' questions?

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts, new-users, old-questions

What should be do with the users' questions that are inactive from a long time ago?

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/102002/62483) is from [this user](https://askubuntu.com/users/45268/santiago) how posted one question in February and after that never came back.

What I'm trying to say is that without the help and testing from the users (that made the questions) the answers **maybe** will be incomplete or subjective. So my suggestion is that the user with a two months *(to give an example)* inactive question and **login**, other user with the same problem take the ownership of this one, and thereby it can contribute with the answer.

Should other user replace the first one? Should the questions be closed? Do you think that this can be useful or not? Should be as they are now?

Comment: A more significant one would be [How do I install Oracle JDK7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) which had more than 100 votes and kviews.  And the user never came back since last August.

Comment: @EmersonHsieh Right, and there are a lot similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no obvious answer to the post then you can:

- Flag or vote for the post to be closed as too localized,
- If lacking further information necessary to answer them they can be closed  as  not really a question.

Comment: What happens is that I was thinking that close the question as `too localized` was wrong because there are many other users waiting for an answer. But I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Is it not better to close something old with no answers and give the opportunity to see a new one with similar content rise than to leave a question rot and wait for an answer for ages? I will close 1000 questions with not answer just for an opportunity to see 1 of those re-created again and answered.

Comment: Agreed. That is the reason of why I'm proposing that some other user appropriates the question, modifying and adapting the question (re-activating it). But is simpler close the question.