# What to do when users have been inactive for months and their question remain open?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have a couple of questions still open

[nVidia GeForce Go 7600? can it ever run unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145675/nvidia-geforce-go-7600-can-it-ever-run-unity)

[UFW is not logging how do I troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113439/ufw-is-not-logging-how-do-i-troubleshoot)

[Will my data be erased if I upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148967/will-my-data-be-erased-if-i-upgrade-from-ubuntu-11-10-to-12-04)

But the users asking those question haven't been active for months.

What to do when users have been inactive for months and there question remain open?

Comment: Related - [What happens to inactive users' questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3971/what-happens-to-inactive-users-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much you can do if a user doesn't come back and accept an answer.

However the *community* can judge the answers based on their quality and vote accordingly. So basically if you leave an answer and the person bails on you but you're getting a bunch of upvotes then the system considers it answered. I think the threshold is 2? (Not sure on that one)

Comment: In this question, i posted an answer, with an upvote of three, http://askubuntu.com/questions/113439/ufw-is-not-logging-how-do-i-troubleshoot/113446#113446 but not accepted. if thats not the threshold what is... i like a challenge

Comment: Only the OP can mark a question as accepted, but if they left there's not much you can do other than making an awesome answer that people will upvote so that it's obviously the best answer.

Comment: Should there be a possibility for the community (who is that, by the way?) to accept an answer if the OP hasn't visited the site for a predetermined period, for example, 6 or 12 months? I don't know all the implications of this change, but I think it would be an improvement.